# Failed to execute start-hdfs.sh in Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and was trying to build a Hadoop standalone server in VMware following these tutorials.
https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html
https://howtoprogram.xyz/2016/11/26/install-hadoop-ubuntu-16-04-standalone-mode/

When I tried to run start-dfs.sh it returned '/usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory', but the file does exist.

[image]

Here is my hdfs-site.xml

[image]

Here is my system variables.

[image]

tried use sudo ./start-dfs.sh, get this. But I am confused with the message because there is no folder under /sbin

[image]

Comment: try using 'sudo', you don't have the permission to run the start-dfs.sh with the user you were logged in. Try it with root user. If it still doesn't work, let me know

Comment: You shouldn't set need to set PATH in /etc/profile... Don't put JAVA_HOME there before you actually defined it. Remove the `.` at the beginning of CLASSPATH (or just use Hortonworks Sandbox VM)

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, thanks for your reply. I tried add sudo in the command but it's still not working. I updated the post and you can see it returned different message. but there is no folder under /sbin

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, thanks for your reply. I removed the . in the Classpath but it changed nothing. I noticed that Hortonworks provides well-configured image but I really want to build it from scratch.

Comment: @Chase I don't think the variables are set properly. Try to run jps command from /root directory. And also try to run 'echo $JAVA_HOME' , does it return the JAVA_HOME value you set in your classpath?

Comment: Hi @Abhinav, I can get the correct JAVA_HOME value when run 'echo $JAVA_HOME' but I don't have access to /root directory, so I switched to root and run 'jps' it returns '1864 Jps'.

Comment: @Abhinav I tried to execute start-dfs.sh when I was logged in as root. and I got 'localhost: Permission denied'

Comment: If jps says nothing other than that, no services are running. Permission defined typically means you didn't setup passwordless SSH. My suggestion is follow the Apache Hadoop documentation rather than external sites... If you really want to do it yourself, Vagrant boxes with provisioning scripts would be better than manual setup

Comment: @Chase if localhost permission is denied then you haven't done localhost passwordless ssh properly. Do that and try again

Comment: Hi @Abhinav. I solved the issue by completely doing it over and I think I found the reason which is the environment setting and the passwordless SSH setting. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @cricket_007. I followed the Apache documentation and it worked. Thanks for you advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason causes the exceptions is the environment setting at /etc/environment

Should set PATH and JAVA_HOME correctly. Set up passwordless SSH is critical as well.